# Entity Reference auto complete term creation on the fly?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes, entities

There is a reason why I'm using an (autocomplete) Entity Reference field on my Content Type, instead of the Drupal's default term reference. It is linked to a taxonomy vocabulary and it's working just fine for my purposes.

What I can't achieve is for a term to be created on-the-fly (auto-creation), if it doesn't already exists in the tax vocabulary, while authoring a new node of that Content Type. Just like drupal's default term reference can do.

Thanks alot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can give a try to this [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module to achieve your goal. It have the option to create new term in auto-complete field.

> Features
>
> ```
> Combo/Select box like selecting.
> Select without entering something.
> Widget for taxaonomy
> Chosen like multiple selecting.
> ```

[image]

> If you want to deny adding new terms, then checkout [Chosen](https://drupal.org/project/chosen). It
>   converts select boxes to autocomplete fields.

Comment: Thanks for this information Bala, I'll take my time to check it out and post a feedback. In the meanwhile I should explain that the reason I used entity reference module is because I needed more complex View relationships (Content referencing Content from field_node...). Do you know if it is possible to have complex relationships like this with Autocomplete Deluxe?

Answer (score 0):

[Entityreference Autocreate](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autocreate) provides this feature (create entity on the fly using Entity Reference autocomplete field).

Also you may look at this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/1472596